# Vertical Align text in an input field

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with vertical aligning text in an input box. I already tried `display:table-cell`. But when I enter space, instead of jumping a line, it goes to the right. Its for multiple lines, not just one line.

```
<div class="bodytext">
   <div class="vertical">
      <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried `line-height` or you may try `padding`.

Comment: Can you also add to your question the CSS you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? Now the text is vertically centered in the textbox.

```css
.bodytext{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.bodytext .vertical input{
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodytext">
 <div class="vertical">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `line-height` or `padding` to input, or if you can share your css or make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```